# using another WS as validation Flask/Rest/Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, rest, flask, flask-restful

I am trying to build a simple web application with 3 web services. Two of my web services are supposed to validate if a student exist in a course or not. This is done by a simple SELECT-query. My third web service should add a student into a database, but only if the student do exist in the specific course.

This is my validation WS which should return a true/false.

```
@app.route('/checkStudOnCourse/<string:AppCode>/<string:ideal>', methods= ["GET"])
def checkStudOnCourseWS(AppCode, ideal):

myCursor3 = mydb.cursor()
query3 = ("SELECT studentID FROM Ideal.course WHERE applicationCode = " + "'" + AppCode + "' AND Ideal = " + "'" + ideal + "'")
myCursor3.execute(query3)
myresult3 = myCursor3.fetchall()

if len(myresult3) == 0:
    return render_template('Invalid.html')
else:
    return jsonify({'Student in course ': True})
```

Below is regResult which should do a SQL insert into a database. I only want the submit to work if the above result is "True", how can I do that? I know I have not done the INSERT query, but that is not a problem. 
What I am unsure about is: How can I only let the submit be be INSERTED if the validation WS is "True".

```
@app.route('/register', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def regResultat():


if request.method == "POST":

    Period = request.form['period']
    #ProvNr = request.form['provNr']
    Grade = request.form['grade']
    Applicationcode = request.form['applicationcode']
    #Datum = request.form['datum']
    Ideal = request.form['ideal']

CheckStudOnCourse = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/checkAppCodeWS/'+Applicationcode+'/'+Ideal
CheckStudOnResp = requests.get(CheckStudOnCourse)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, such syntax:

`if len(myresult3) == 0`, can be simplified by `if myresult3`, because Python evaluates that implicitly to bool.

Secondly, if you once returned from function, there is no need to write an else statement:

```
    if len(myresult3) == 0:
        return render_template('Invalid.html')  #  < -- in case 'True',
                                                #  it returns here, otherwise 
                                                #  function keeps going"""

     return jsonify({'Student in course ': True})  # < -- in case 'False', it is returned here
```

Focusing on your issue, you could do that:

Get your value from ws

```
CheckStudOnCourse = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/checkAppCodeWS/'+Applicationcode+'/'+Ideal
CheckStudOnResp = requests.get(CheckStudOnCourse)
```

Extract json from it:

```
if result_as_json.status == 200:
    result_as_json = CheckStudOnResp.json()  #  < -- it is now a dict
```

Do some checks:

```
if result_as_json.get('Student in course', False):  #  I highly suggest to use other 
                                                   #  convention to name json keys 
                                                   #  e.g. Student in course -> 
                                                   #  student_exists_in_course
    #  do your code here
```

Comment: Thanks for ur feedback and comments on my code. I understand what you are saying and why it is better. When I try to do this I get an error saying "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"
"if stud_exists_in_course.get('Student in course', True):

        myCursor4.execute("INSERT INTO  Ladok.resultat (Kurskod, Ideal, betyg, datum, anmalningskod) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                         (Kurskod, Ideal, Betyg, Period, Anmalningskod))
        mydb4.commit()"

Comment: Can you show me what `CheckStudOnResp` contains? Simply `print(str(CheckStudOnResp))`

Comment: Does response have status `200 OK`?

Comment: I got an <Response [200]> in my console. And also "TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement."
I added the print(str(checkstudOnResp)) before my IF statement.

Comment: If I only run http://127.0.0.1:5000/checkStudOnCourse/ltu-123/jonoke-6 (Which is my CheckStudOnCoursewS(Appcode, Ideal) then I get a valid return ("student in course, TRUE")

It might be easier to see in my snippet. https://snipplr.com/view/329870/flask/

Comment: Yes, you should get an error - that was for debug purposes, you may now delete that print. If you get 200, then everything is correct. Does `requests` lib you are using is that one: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ ?

Comment: As you print `result_ast_json' it contains some data?

Comment: You could also try to add `if CheckStudOnResp.status == 200:
    result = CheckStudOnResp .json()`

Comment: Thanks again for your time, really appreciate it. Yes I am using that requests lib and python which supports it. Not really sure what you mean with "`result_ast_json'". And when should I use the "result" from "result = CheckStudOnResp .json()"?

Comment: I meants `result_as_json` sorry.

Comment: Edited main anwser, you may look there.

Comment: it seems to be working now. Glad you helped. I have ofc up voted your answer.

Comment: Thank you. Good luck with your project.